# Import Typescript modules in Svelte Component

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I have setup `svelte-preprocess` so I can do this successfully:

```
<script lang="typescript">
    let someConstant:string = "some constant";
    console.log({someConstant});
</script>
```

That works.  But I don't know how to externalise that constant.  If I try:

```
<script lang="typescript">
    import {someConstant} from './SomeTypescript.ts'
    console.log({someConstant});
</script>
```

I get this error message:

`error TS2691: An import path cannot end with a '.ts' extension. Consider importing './SomeTypescript' instead.`

When I change it to

```
<script lang="typescript">
    import {someConstant} from './SomeTypescript'
    console.log({someConstant});
</script>
```

I get this error:

`Error: Could not resolve './SomeTypescript' from src/tom/ManageAirtableModels.svelte`

Whats the right way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install the rollup plugin for typescript to handle non-svelte files:

```
yarn add -D @rollup/plugin-typescript typescript tslib
```

Add `plugin-typescript` to your `plugins` list in `rollup.config.js`:

```js
//....
import autoProcess from 'svelte-preprocess'
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript'

export default {
  ...
  plugins: [
    typescript(),

    svelte({
      preprocess: autoProcess(),
      ...
    })
    ...
  ]
}
```

Now `import` won't require a `.ts` extension:

```html
<script lang="typescript">
    import {someConstant} from './SomeTypescript'
    console.log({someConstant});
</script>
```

Comment: For those coming here with this problem despite having rollup setup this way, try pointing the rollup typescript plugin's `tsconfig` parameter to the tsconfig you're using for Svelte. Worked for me.